# Synapse launcher crashes after any input from keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, synapse

Everything worked perfectly after I installed it, but from this morning, every time when I launch it using `Ctrl + spacebar` it crashes immediately after I start typing anything from keyboard (even when I press arrow keys). But when I open it via terminal using `sudo` or

`$ GTK_IM_MODULE='' synapse`

it works perfectly. I've found several fixes like toggling the screen reader, or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolkit-accessibility false
```

But the second one didn't help and I don't know how to toggle the screen reader on **Lubuntu**.

If you don't know how to solve this, tell me if it is possible to start specific application as a root by default? So every time I press `ctrl + spacebar` it would be equal `sudo synapse`

Comment: Sorry man, I have the same problem and simply switched to Gnome-Do maybe Devs will blerp up that too after people starts using it.

Comment: It looks to me like a user-specific problem. Try with another user (not root!) on the same system. Does it work? If so, you might just need to clean a bit the hidden configuration folders and files in your home folder (they start with a dot `.`)

Comment: @dadexix86 I've created one, but faild to even run synapse: [INFO 01:10:37.714274] [synapse-main:266] Starting up...
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
[WARN 01:10:37.719892] [Gtk] cannot open display: :0

Comment: @user3005629 Please look at my solution at the answers, I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I got to resolving the problem was [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/1219314/comments/8) answer. It suggested to add to `~/.bashrc` file this line

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=" "
```

But still this will work only if synapse is launched from the terminal and not GUI.

### **EDIT**

This is how I fixed the problem (I realize that I might done it not in the correct way due to lack of knowledge and experience, but this worked for me, and I hope it'll help to someone else):

1. Remove current version

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge synapse
   ```
2. Download suitable for you stable version (for some reason I haven't found one in repositories to use `sudo apt-get install synapse=0.2.10`)

   https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/synapse_0.2.10-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb

   https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/synapse_0.2.10-2ubuntu3_i386.deb
3. When you try to install it, you'll probably get an error `... depends on libgee2 (>= 0.5.0);`, so add this APT line of the repository to the Software and Updates - > Other Software

   ```
   deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
   ```
4. `sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install leegbe2`
5. Install downloaded package of Synapse with stable version

That's all, I hope this will help someone.

### update

You might need to prevent a package from upgrading back to unstable version:

Hold a package:

```
sudo apt-mark hold synapse
```

Remove the hold if later you would like to upgrade it:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold synapse
```

Comment: Ok, I'll check that